# How to animate folding a paper plane in blender 2.8

Tags: animation, modifiers, rigging, keyframes

I have made a paper plane by folding a flat mesh plain with a mirror modifier.
I would like to animate the folding from start to finish.
Is there a quick simple way to do this?[image]

Comment: Yes there is. You can quickly and simple rig it and animate using rig or equally easy and simple create a shape key for each step of folding and then animate the shape keys.

Comment: Although it's not a practical approach, you can also do this fully procedurally: https://twitter.com/chiu_hans/status/1194220263778353152

Comment: I tried the shape key but the paper doesn't fold, it sort of just changes shape to appear to look like folding. I have attached my Blend file link. Could you tell me if maybe there is a setting problem?https://www.dropbox.com/s/ibu8ew14thqbvm5/paper%20plane_unfold.blend11?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You could try assign the model with shape keys. You can assign some bones to the shape keys and with some drivers that could fold up each section, with out going through each side one at a time, and key frame it later.